# What happens if I update my extension WITHOUT incrementing the version in the manifest?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I know that when you publish a new version of your extension to the Chrome Store, you're supposed to increment the version in the manifest file. BUT what if I publish an update WITHOUT incrementing the version? What I would want to happen is that the old users that already have the extension don't get the update, but any new installers get the latest version. Is that what would happen?

The reason I want to take this approach is that the new version of my extension will request increased permissions, and I don't want the extension to auto-disable for all my old users where they are then asked if they want to enable it given the new permissions, and that's what happens when there's a permission level increase. I'm afraid that if that happens, my install counts will drop.

Comment: Use optional_permissions instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can't upload a package with the same version number as the already published one, just tried myself and got this error:

```
An error occurred: Failed to process your item.

Invalid version number in manifest: 1.8.2. Please make sure the newly uploaded package has a larger version in file manifest.json than the published package: 1.8.2.
```

Comment: Oh wow, I wasn't expecting that. Dang, there goes my plan! Thanks for the answer.